# Price of most expensive woocomerce product in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to get price(or id) of the most expensive product while beeing in woocomerce admin panel. With the code below i keep getting infinite loop, eventhough im not sure if this is correct way to do it. Tried many of different part of functions form stack but it didnt help me.

```
unction test() {

$args = array(
    'category' => array( 'blackcat' ),
    'orderby'  => 'name',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'test' );

$query = array(
    'limit' => 1,
    'post_type'=> 'product',
    'orderby' => 'price',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    
);
$the_query= new WP_Query($query);


    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        
        }
    
     } else {
         // no posts found
     }
     // Restore original Post Data 
     wp_reset_postdata();

   }
    
  }

}

add_action( 'parse_query', 'apply_my_custom_product_filters' );
```

Both returns Allowed memory size of ..... bytes exhausted in /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was hooking to wrong place. Sould have use ‘restrict_manage_posts’

```
 add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'yet', 10);

 function yet(){
 $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        'orderby' => 'price',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

 }
```